# Problem with Set Theory Counting Principle

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to apply the counting principle to the following:

"Of 300 people:
35 - bicycle and car.
40 - car and bus.
60 - bicycle and bus.
90 - bicycle.
70 - car.
105 - bus.
25 - bicycle, car, and bus."

I just don't know how this adds up to 300. If i apply the principle, I get:

90 (bicycle) + 105 (bus) + 70 (car) - 35 (bicycle and car) - 40 (car and bus) - 60 (bicycle and bus) + 25 (bicycle, car, and bus).

This equals to 155.

I don't understand how I can get 300 participants from the above, can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: It is because some of the people who ride bicycles and drive cars, maybe also ride the bus..how do you know that $105$ people ride the bus? You have people that belong in more than 1 group

Comment: @OriaGruber Yeah, some people belong to more than one group, but to my knowledge that is what the counting principle formula does, it gives you the total unique number of participants, but in this case, it doesn't add up to 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there is 145 pedestrians. You have 155 people split between 3 modes of travel and the balance of the 300 who do not use one of the three modes?

Comment: Oh, how American of me. I didn't even assume that some people can just walk :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact text of your homework ? But yeah, you're applying the counting formula correctly.